# InvalidOperationException in a custom EF Core save method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am writing a custom save generic method for our framework in EF Core. The idea is to have a method that can make partial updates.

The code is like this:

```
public IEnumerable<T> UpdateEntitiesByProperties(IEnumerable<UpdateByPropertiesData<T>> entitiesAndProperties)
{
   List<T> entities = new List<T>();

   foreach (var entityAndProperties in entitiesAndProperties)
   {
        T contextEntity = this.context.Find<T>(entityAndProperties.Entity.Id);
        EntityEntry<T> changeTrackerEntityEntry = this.context.Entry(contextEntity);

        changeTrackerEntityEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entityAndProperties.Entity);

        foreach (var property in changeTrackerEntityEntry.Properties.Where(p => !p.Metadata.IsConcurrencyToken))
        {
            property.IsModified = entityAndProperties.UpdatedProperties.Contains(property.Metadata.Name);
        }

     entities.Add(contextEntity);
   }

   return entities;
}
```

If I change the code to this, it works correctly:

```
public IEnumerable<T> UpdateEntitiesByProperties(IEnumerable<UpdateByPropertiesData<T>> entitiesAndProperties)
{
   List<T> entities = new List<T>();

   foreach (var entityAndProperties in entitiesAndProperties)
   {
        T contextEntity = this.context.Find<T>(entityAndProperties.Entity.Id);
        EntityEntry<T> changeTrackerEntityEntry = this.context.Entry(contextEntity);

        changeTrackerEntityEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entityAndProperties.Entity);

        foreach (var property in changeTrackerEntityEntry.Properties.Where(p => !p.Metadata.IsConcurrencyToken))
        {
            if(entityAndProperties.UpdatedProperties.Contains(property.Metadata.Name)
            {
                property.CurrentValue = typeof(T).GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredProperty(property.Metadata.Name).GetValue(entityAndProperties.Entity);  
            }
        }

     entities.Add(contextEntity);
   }

   return entities;
}
```

The method is working with simple entities but throws an InvalidOperationException when the entity in entitiesAndProperties does not contain a required field.

The exception text is:

> The property 'Name' on entity type 'User' is marked as null, but this cannot be saved because the property is marked as required.

It should not be a problem, because the entity already exists in database with the required field value, `contextEntity` reflects that, but seems the `CurrentValues.SetValues` overrides this.

Comment: Makes sense.... Then add the required field.. or remove constraint. What is the question?

Comment: @GiladGreen The entity in database already has the required fields. entityAndProperties  does not, but should not be a problem because i change IsModified properties.

Comment: `changeTrackerEntityEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entityAndProperties.Entity);` already marks properties as `Modified` when they actually are different. What is the aim of the code following this statement?

Comment: @GertArnold The aim of this code is to not change the values of properties with do not have value in `entityAndProperties.Entity`

Comment: OK, I don't know what `UpdateByPropertiesData<T>` is, but I would avoid `CurrentValues.SetValues` altogether if you only want to change a subset of properties.

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with @Gert Arnold comment that you should probably avoid `CurrentValues.SetValues` in such scenario, the code looks to me pretty legal, so I'm considering this to be a current EF Core implementation bug.

It's the only case AFAIK which doesn't change the `CurrentValue` of the property in the target object, but marks it somewhere internally as invalid. Normally setting `IsModified = false` or `CurrentValue = OriginalValue` restores the property value, but not in this case (because the value is the same), which is ok, but the problem is that it also doesn't remove the "invalid mark", which I think is the bug.

I would suggest using your current workaround and posting the issue to their issue tracker.

Comment: I opened the issue after posting this issue because I thought it was legal use of the API... This is the posted issue https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/8465 They haven't made an statement yet saying that this is not correct code.

Comment: @AlexDRL That's basically what I'm saying in the answer - *the code looks to me pretty legal, so I'm considering this to be a current EF Core implementation bug*